# preg_replace to find and replace a string in php

Tags: regex, preg-replace

Using preg_replace to find symbols + or - contains inside of any string, if found means replace that string with double quote("") or single quote('').

For eg:

1.if sometext+sometext replace to "sometext+sometext"

2.if sometext-sometext replace to "sometext-sometext"

Comment: Repeat of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18119141/1578604). Please elaborate on your previous question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: @Jerry They are both. Off topic: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @HamZa I was hoping the OP would post some code sooner or later in the other question, but yes, until then, they're off-topic. xP

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
echo preg_replace('/\b\w+[+-]\w+\b/', '"$0"', $text);
```